# How to write data in a QLineEdit widget, from output of QFileDialog::getOpenFileName in Qt 5 under C++

Tags: c++, qt, widget, global-variables

I am creating an application with Qt 5, in C++.  I want to let the user choose a file, and then write the (absolute) path of the chosen file in a `QLineEdit` widget.
This path will be then read by other widgets, in order to process the chosen file.

I have managed to connect a button to the `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName`, using a slot-event-connect approach, so that pressing the button, the "Choose a file" window appears, and I managed to save the path in a `QString` variable.

I have doubts on what to do next. Should I use another event-slot-connect? But what would be the event? the closure of the `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName window`?

I like the idea of using the `QLineEdit` widget as a 'global variable', because the user can also paste the path manually, but I am open to other solutions.

Is the event-slot-connect approach a good option?

I have previous experience with PyQT, used in Python (and I have already realized the application in Python, with a callback function), but I am rather new to C++. In particular, I struggle to learn the proper ways to pass parameters between objects.

This is what I have done so far:

**myApp.h**

```
#ifndef MYAPP_H
#define MYAPP_H

#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSize>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QString>
#include <QLineEdit>


class MainWindow : public QWidget {

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    
private slots:
    
    void SelectInput();
        
};

#endif /* MYAPP_H */
```

**myApp.cpp**

```
#include "myApp.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)   // questa è la definizione del costruttore
    : QWidget(parent) {
        
    setWindowTitle("Frames extraction");
    
    auto *layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    
    auto *inputbox = new QLineEdit(this);
    layout->addWidget(inputbox, 0, 0);
    inputbox->setFixedSize(QSize(800, 25));
    
    auto *inputBtn = new QPushButton("select input");
    layout->addWidget(inputBtn, 0, 2);
    
    
    connect(inputBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::SelectInput);
    
}



void MainWindow::SelectInput()
{
    
    QString inputFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Select a file...");
    
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "myApp.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    MainWindow window;
    window.resize(600, 350);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: *"I managed to save the path in a `QString` variable."* -- This looks to me like a reason to remove the `QFileDialog` from your question, or maybe move it to the end of your question as some additional context (in case you have an XY problem). A more focused question would be along the lines of *"How do I put the value of a `QString` variable in a `QLineEdit`?"* Or is the problem finding the `QLineEdit` (in which case the `QFileDialog` might be relevant)? Or something else? Being more precise with your question would help get more helpful answers.

Comment: @JaMiT my problem is the confusion between the multiple 'slots-event-connect' structures that I have in my code. Being new to this approach I don't know if adding another slot is the right way to go, given that I already have one (from the QFileDialog, indeed). This is why I mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in the code reported in the question:

- The definition of the `MainWindow::SelectInput()` slot function in the myApp.cpp file should create a QDialog instance, not just call it, and then should contain also a 'connect()' which connects this dialog with the QLineEdit widget,
- The `QLineEdit` widget should be declared in the header, and not in the creator, so that it is global to the class, and can be reached by the 'connect()' instance mentioned in the previous point.

So, those are the amended versions of the three files, that solve the problem and give the required functionality:

**myApp.h**

```
#ifndef MYAPP_H
#define MYAPP_H

#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSize>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QString>
#include <QLineEdit>


class MainWindow : public QWidget {

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    
    QLineEdit *inputbox;
    
private slots:
    
    void SelectInput();
        
};

#endif /* MYAPP_H */
```

**myApp.cpp**

```
#include "myApp.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)   // questa è la definizione del costruttore
    : QWidget(parent) {
        
    setWindowTitle("Frames extraction");
    
    auto *layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    
    inputbox = new QLineEdit(this);
    layout->addWidget(inputbox, 0, 0);
    inputbox->setFixedSize(QSize(800, 25));
    
    auto *inputBtn = new QPushButton("select input");
    layout->addWidget(inputBtn, 0, 2);
    
    
    connect(inputBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::SelectInput);
    
}



void MainWindow::SelectInput()
{
    auto *theDialog = new QFileDialog(this);
    
    connect(theDialog, &QFileDialog::fileSelected, inputbox,                        
                                                &QLineEdit::setText);
    theDialog->exec();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "myApp.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    MainWindow window;
    window.resize(600, 350);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the selection to a line edit, it is easy:

```
QObject::connect(theFileDialog, &QFileDialog::fileSelected,
                 theLineEdit, &QLineEdit::setText);
```

If you need more complex logic in between, the  I reckommend a lambda.

Comment: Thank @hyde! I guess this would be enough, I don't need the lambda. However, I am struggling with C++ syntax, could you please give more context to your answer? Where should I put this 'connect()'? in the constructor? how do I get the 'theFileDialog' variable identifying the dialog window? I am sorry for the triviality of those questions, I am still new to the language... :-/

Comment: could you please explain where to create the 'theFileDialog' instance? If I create it in the constructor, it is not accessible in the connect function, and if I create it in the connect function, it is not accessible from the constructor...
Could you please copy my working example and insert your connect function in it?

Comment: @Fabio I'll edit my answer if I have time, but a quick hint: You can't use `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` convenience method here. You need the few more lines to create the dialog, connect the signal, then open the dialog. IIRC docs have good example code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, hyde! I was reaching the same conclusion...!
I am reading the https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/tutorials-addressbook.html tutorial where they implement a "find" dialog, and I was guessing that I need to create a dialog. Thanks for your hint, it is reassuring me! I look forward for your answer edit, if possible.

Comment: @fabio for example code, check out the sources: https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog.cpp.html#_ZN11QFileDialog15getOpenFileNameEP7QWidgetRK7QStringS4_S4_PS2_6QFlagsINS_6OptionEE which calls  https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog.cpp.html#_ZN11QFileDialog14getOpenFileUrlEP7QWidgetRK7QStringRK4QUrlS4_PS2_6QFlagsINS_6OptionEERK11QStringList which creates the dialog. You can just copy those two functions, even (note LGPL license, probably not a problem for you), and add signal connect before calling `exec`.

Comment: hyde, I am almost there, but I have a "newbie problem"... :-/  now in my SelectInput() function I have added the declaration 'auto *theFileDialog = new QFileDialog(this);'  before the 'connect' that you suggest, and 'theFileDialog->exec();' after it... but I get an "error: 'theLineEdit' was not declared in this scope" (actually, I call it 'inputbox'. But I have indeed created the 'inputbox' QLinedit instance in the constructor! and it should be global! There is something I still don't get... maybe it is because I created a pointer, in the constructor...

Comment: maybe, I need to create a "getfilepath()" and a "setfilepath{}" to access the content of the QLineEdit widget?

Comment: @Fabio the usual solution is to make the line edit pointer a member variable. Another would be to give it name and call the find child method of QObject when you need it.

Comment: @hyhe thanks again! in the meanwhile I managed to compile and run! Yes, I declared the line edit in the header, so that it becomes global to the class, as you suggest. I have posted the full amended code.
I am still learning, I thank you so much for your inputs, you encouraged me to insist, and eventually to solve the problem! And most importantly, I am learning "the basics"! :)